# Galaxy S II Default Video and Music Player apk for CM 10.3.1

Tags: cyanogenmod

I recently installed CyanogenMod 10.3.1 on my Samsung Galaxy S II (i9100)
I lost my default music and video player. Can anyone provide me with working apks of the applications? Those were my favorite media players.

Comment: OEM's applications often (not to say always) require OEM's framework which isn't and cannot be included in CyanogenMod.

Comment: So does it only work for TouchWiz framework? Are you sure that there is no chance of a modified version?

Comment: Maybe someone tried, but there's also legal reason involved (copyrighted software...)

Comment: I completely overlooked that. :P